Settings datasources for XY Plot in Grafana panel plugin
I am a newbie writing a Grafana Panel plugin (something like already existing XY Chart). My plugin uses datasource of InfluxDB. The platfom I am writing it on is windows.
I need to create the settings for selecting columns out of query that the user inputs - values for X and Y out of those columns will be used for building the dots in the chart.
There are a few details that I unfortunately lack of knowing:

Are there any documentation on standard properties of Grafana that may be accessed? (I managed to spot a few like "data.series")?

In module.ts which one of adds shall I use? Shall it be addSelect (it seems to be the closest to what I need for selection out of items)?

Are there any example plugins (except the official Grafana ones - they give little to no examples of how to render the dots on the chart and so on) or any documentation/blog/tutorial in which there are relevant examples?

It would also be nice to see the default Grafana plugins source code to see how they work. Are they available anywhere?


Feel free to send links to the relevant literature.
Much obliged to anyone who answers to this post
import { PanelPlugin, FieldOverrideContext } from '@grafana/data';
import { SimpleOptions } from './types';
import { SimplePanel } from './components/SimplePanel';

export const plugin = new PanelPlugin<SimpleOptions>(SimplePanel).setPanelOptions((builder) => {

  return builder
    .addTextInput({
      path: 'text',
      name: 'Simple text option',
      description: 'Description of panel option',
      defaultValue: 'Default value of text input option',
    })
    .addBooleanSwitch({
      path: 'showSeriesCount',
      name: 'Show series counter',
      defaultValue: false,
    })
    .addRadio({
      path: 'seriesCountSize',
      defaultValue: 'sm',
      name: 'Series counter size',
      settings: {
        options: [
          {
            value: 'sm',
            label: 'Small',
          },
          {
            value: 'md',
            label: 'Medium',
          },
          {
            value: 'lg',
            label: 'Large',
          },
        ],
      },
      showIf: (config) => config.showSeriesCount,
    })
    .addSelect({
      path: 'xAxisVal',
      name: 'X Axis Value Source',
      description: 'Select the column to take values for the X axis from',
      settings: {
        getOptions: async (context: FieldOverrideContext) => {  // Correctly typed context
          const options: Array<{ label: string; value: string }> = [];

          if (context.data && context.data.length > 0) {
            context.data.forEach(dataFrame => {
              dataFrame.fields.forEach(field => {
                options.push({ label: field.name, value: field.name });
              });
            });
          }

          return options;
        },
      } as any, // Type assertion to bypass type checking
      defaultValue: '', // Set a sensible default value
    })
    .addSelect({
      path: 'yAxisVal',
      name: 'Y Axis Value Source',
      description: 'Select the column to take values for the Y axis from',
      settings: {
        getOptions: async (context: FieldOverrideContext) => {  // Correctly typed context
          const options: Array<{ label: string; value: string }> = [];

          if (context.data && context.data.length > 0) {
            context.data.forEach(dataFrame => {
              dataFrame.fields.forEach(field => {
                options.push({ label: field.name, value: field.name });
              });
            });
          }

          return options;
        },
      } as any, // Type assertion to bypass type checking
      defaultValue: ''
    })
    .addTextInput({
      path: 'xLabel',
      name: 'X-Axis Label',
      description: 'Displayed Axis legend text',
      defaultValue: 'ATTT',
    })
    .addTextInput({
      path: 'yLabel',
      name: 'Y-Axis Label',
      description: 'Displayed Axis legend text',
      defaultValue: 'KWWW',
    })
    .addBooleanSwitch({
      path: 'displayBgLines',
      name: 'Background current lines',
      defaultValue: true,
    });
});


Even though when I switch to the defauly XYChart from Grafana, I am able to see different fields to select from, when I switch to my plugin - there is nothing available. The one of interest are xAxisVal and yAxisVal

Have you looked at source codes of built-in XYchart? Available at https://github.com/grafana/grafana/tree/main/public/app/plugins/panel/xychart
